# Help with JFET circuit analysis

Tags: jfet, homework

Just having trouble analysing the following circuit with the information given. 
[image]

where k=0.16mA/volt^2, Vt = -1.7V and A = 1V.

I believe you have to first find an expression for V_gs but the capacitor and resistors are throwing me off on how to analyse this circuit as it isn't similar to any of the previous examples I have looked at or anything I can find online. Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: *I believe you have to first find an expression for V_gs* **Why?** My first step would be to analyze **how** the circuit works. What does the bottom JFET do? What does the other JFET do? How does that relate to R1, R2 and C? Hint: think about the **DC** voltages and currents first so forget about the AC signal. An amplifier can only work properly for AC if it has the correct DC biasing right?

Comment: The resistors and capacitor are simply there to provide bias.  They won't affect the gain and output range much as long as it's correctly biased.  The bottom JFET is simply a current source...the spec should tell you how much current it will pass at Vgs=0.  That should simplify it.